# model.matrix with assigned values

Tags: r, model.matrix

Suppose I have the following data.frame:

```
df=data.frame(cat=c("a","b","c"),y=c(1,2,3))
```

Taking the `model.matrix` of the categories (cat) converts them to dummy variables as follows:

```
model.matrix(~0+cat,df)


 cata catb catc
1    1    0    0
2    0    1    0
3    0    0    1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$cat
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

However, I wish to have those dummy variables be assigned the values in df$y instead. One possible solution I can think of is to row multiply with y.

However, I'm guessing there are better purpose built functions for this?

So basically, what is the most efficient way of converting dummy variables to a given vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be we can try

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df, cat~y, value.var="y", fill=0)
#  1 2 3
#a 1 0 0
#b 0 2 0
#c 0 0 3
```

Or using `model.matrix`

```
model.matrix(~0 + cat, df) *df$y
```

Comment: That _would_ seem to be the glaringly obvious answer. One does wonder.

Comment: Would the first method be considered to be the more efficient way. Especially considering that there is no multiplication operation?

Comment: @Sachin_ruk  If you are using `dcast` from `library(data.table)`, it would be more efficient.  But, you can benchmark with `library(microbenchmark)` on a bigger dataset to see which one is efficient.